# Network Security

Tags: cryptography

Token cards display a number that changes periodically, perhaps every minute. Each such
device has a unique secret key. A human can prove possession of a particular such device by
entering the displayed number into a computer system. The computer system knows the
secret keys of each authorized device. How would you design such a device?

Comment: [This](http://www.rsa.com/node.aspx?id=1156)? You might have better luck on a crypto or math forum.

Comment: I wouldn't. I would buy them from a company that knows what they are doing and are producing the devices in large enough numbers to keep the per-unit cost down.

Comment: ...it would also save me the hassle of designing the hardware and developing the software for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this kind of authentication scheme is part of ["two-factor authentication"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication).  In many popular 2FA solutions the user owns a small calculator-size device with a preconfigured PIN key. Upon entering the PIN, a One time password (OTP) is generated.
By entering the generated password, associated with his username, the user "proves" he has the device and knows the PIN code.  [Aladdin's safeword](http://www.safenet-inc.com/aladdin-content/safeword/default/) is such a device, popular in corporate/VPN/WifiPEAP environments.
It's also nowadays centralised and OTP are now often sent through SMS.

If you google around for the "How to implement two-factor authentication", you'll find numerous good articles.  The topic is complex and involves many different technologies.

You can try [this article](http://howto.techworld.com/security/3223170/how-to-implement-two-factor-authentication-with-windows-server-2008-nps/) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

In the token device:

- A stable clock with maximum deviation of 10s/year (can be done using quartz crystal oscillator), synchronized to UTC.
- A public key stored individual to each device
- Some random saltID, which also serves as the user identification value, so it should have reasonable length
- A hash function

The number the token shows is generated by combining the saltID with the current time, hashing the value and encrypting it with the public key.

Upon login the authentication system reperforms the steps of the authentication token, minus of the public key encryption (i.e. it just computes the hash). The crypted hash is decrypted and compared to the calculated hash. If both match the token is accepted as valid.

The better authentication tokens have some numeric input, where the user can enter his PIN code, for protecting against loss or theft.